# Can any body clearly explain when to use which statistical distance such as KL-divergence, Bhattacharyya distance?

Tags: statistics

I am working on data mining problems and I have to find similarity between pair of objects. I know what all the statistical distances are, but fails to  find any source that define when to use which statistical distance?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not going to be a plain "use that" because there is not such a thing in statistics.

I found my self in the past using statistical distances such as Mahalanobis, which is a particular case of Bhattacharyya distance when dealing with similar problems. I used KL-divergence when building trees (minimun spanning trees etc).

A main difference between the two is that Bhattacharyya is a metric and KL is not, so you have to take this into account when thinking about what kind of information you want to extract about your data points.

In brief, I would use the Bhattacharyya.